# How to transform the complex number $\frac{(1+i)^{29}}{1-i}$ to the form $a + bi$?

Tags: complex-numbers

My problem is I have to transform $\displaystyle \frac{(1+i)^{29}}{1-i}$ on its binomial representation $(a + bi)$.

I was thinking about transforming that into it polar representation and then reverse the process to get the binomial one, but it gets tricky! Any help would be really appreciated as I'm studying this subject for one of my finals.

Comment: write both in polar form and use De Moivres thoerem for the numerator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\frac{(1+i)^{29}}{1-i}=\frac{(1+i)^{30}}{(1-i)(1+i)}=\frac{[(1+i)^2]^{15}}2$$

Now $(1+i)^2=\cdots=2i$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply top and bottom by the conjugate of the bottom. The conjugate of $ a + b i$ is $ a - b i$.

Comment: this does not help, as you would have to expand $(1+i)^{30}$ to get the answer

Comment: @Ant It's now part of the accepted answer. The other part is expanding $(1 + i)^{30}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are clever tricks you can use here, but the truth is that even large exponents are never *very* hard.

To calculate $x^{29}$, calculate $x^2$, $x^4$, $x^8$, $x^{16}$ by repeated squaring ($4$ multiplications) and then $x^{29} = x^{16} \cdot x^8 \cdot x^4 \cdot x$ (another $4$ multiplications).

So with no knowledge of what $x$ is at all, you can already reduce a tiresome $28$ operations to only $8$.